# Automation Test Gradle Project using Selenium, can we keep test scripts outside src/test/java folder and access and if yes, how can we implement it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maven

In a maven/gradle project, can we keep source code of automation testing outside src/test/java or src/main/java folders, keeping that code creating a new folder inside project root? If yes, how can we implement it

My understanding is, we can maintain all automation scripts inside of src folder only and access it

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can indicate the source folder(s) in the gradle configuration file.

This question shows how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31078965/2252076